# Oracle query to migrate some columns into one

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, which looks like this:

- There's a primary key (`PK`). I need it (obviously).
- `AA`, `BB` and `CC` has 6 versions (up to `AA5`, `BB5`, `CC5`). All of them strings.

  - `AA`, `BB` and `CC` are bound to each other: if there's `AA`, there should be `BB` and `CC`.
  - They have to be filled continuously: there is no such situation where `AA`, `BB`, `CC` are filled, `AA2`, `BB2`, `CC2` not filled, and `AA3`, `BB3`, `CC3` are filled!
- There are other columns, but I don't need them.

`PK  AA  BB  CC  AA2  BB2  CC2  AA3  BB3  CC3 
  1   X   Y   Z    D    F    G
  2   Q   W   E
  3   U   I   O    P    H    K    L    R    M`

What I want to do with the query:

- I need `PK`.
- All `AA` should be placed into 1 column called `AAA`.
- All `BB` should be placed into 1 column called `BBB`.
- All `CC` should be placed into 1 column called `CCC`.

`PK  AAA  BBB  CCC 
  1    X    Y    Z 
  1    D    F    G 
  2    Q    W    E 
  3    U    I    O 
  3    P    H    K 
  3    L    R    M`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `unpivot` operator, unpivoting was done with a cross join to a small table (single column, as many rows as columns or groups of columns need to be unpivoted: in your case, six - or in the simplified example, three).

The reason for this approach - vs. the simple but inefficient `union all` approach - is that you only need to read the base table once.

Like this:  ("table1" is the name of your base table)

```
select t.pk,
       case h.lvl  when 1 then aa
                   when 2 then aa2
                   when 3 then aa3 
            end as aa,
       case h.lvl  when 1 then bb
                   when 2 then bb2
                   when 3 then bb3
            end as bb,
       case h.lvl  when 1 then cc
                   when 2 then cc2
                   when 3 then cc3
            end as cc
from   table1 t
       cross join
       ( select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 3 ) h
;
```

**NOTE**:  This will also produce rows where aa, bb and cc are NULL (when, for example, aa3, bb3 and cc3 were null in the base table). These can be removed, if needed, by wrapping the cross join within an outer query and adding a `where` clause, for example: `where aa is not null`.

**UNPIVOT**

Here is how this can be done in Oracle 11.1 and higher. Groups of columns can be unpivoted in a single `unpivot` operation, like so:

```
select  pk, aa, bb, cc
from    table1
unpivot ( (aa, bb, cc) for rn in ( (aa, bb, cc), (aa2, bb2, cc2), (aa3, bb3, cc3) ) );
```

Comment: Thanks. I've also forget grouping in `unpivot`. I'll test all 3 solutions on Monday at my workplace. I'm really curious about the performance.

Answer (score 3):

You can use  `UNPIVOT`

**EDIT:** There was no need of `JOIN` as in my original answer, thanks to @mathguy, I was able to correct it.

```
select pk,AAA,BBB,CCC FROM YOURTABLE 
UNPIVOT 
  ( (AAA,BBB,CCC) 
      FOR col in ( (aa, bb, cc), (aa2, bb2, cc2), (aa3, bb3, cc3) )
   )
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e657a/29)

Comment: `UNPIVOT` is only available with 11g and later. Although as all versions prior to 12c are deprecated this should be moot.

Comment: Thanks. I thought there's a something else besides unpivot and union.

Comment: Ugh.  When you need to unpivot groups of columns, three at a time, that can be done in a single `unpivot` operation - no need to unpivot three times and then join the results.

Comment: @mathguy : I tried that, but couldn't get it to work to give the expected output. Maybe i was missing something? .

Comment: @mathguy : Oops. I was making a silly mistake because of which I could not get the desired output; corrected now. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 3):

Use `UNION ALL` operator:

```
SELECT pk, aa As aaa,bb as bbb,cc as ccc 
FROM table1

UNION ALL

SELECT pk, aa2,bb2,cc2
FROM table1
WHERE aa2 IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT pk, aa3,bb3,cc3
FROM table1
WHERE aa3 IS NOT NULL
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a7487/4

```
| PK | AAA | BBB | CCC |
|----|-----|-----|-----|
|  1 |   D |   F |   G |
|  1 |   X |   Y |   Z |
|  2 |   Q |   W |   E |
|  3 |   P |   H |   K |
|  3 |   L |   R |   M |
|  3 |   U |   I |   O |
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought there's a something else besides unpivot and union.

Comment: @junpet - there is! Unpivoting was done before the `unpivot` operator was introduced; and `union all` wasn't it. You only need to read the base data once, not six times.